# WMZ files from MSWord when porting to HTML

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, clipboard, clipboard-pictures

When I copy the clipboard data in C# using `Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html).ToString();`, 
there are ".wmz" files getting stored in the "temp" path. (it's present in the `v:imagedata src` section)

There are math symbols like delta in the original Word file. And these are not "Windows Media Player" video files (which also have the extension of ".wmz"). Then I copy this temp file to a permanent location and updated the `src` path and clear the clipboard. But my new HTML content doesn't display the actual image (stored as ".wmz" format).

But for regular ".png" or ".jpg" files in the HTML, this approach works fine. I am facing issues only with these ".wmz" files.

Can someone please help in correctly converting these ".wmz" files to a format acceptable in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "[Compressed Windows Metafile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile)" format. I think you can work with `System.Drawing` to directly convert it to a .jpg or .png, just like a .wmf (which is saved to a .png format automatically in `System.Drawing`).